# WPF SelectedItem binding to source doesn't affect keyboard navigation

Tags: wpf, datagrid

OK, so I'm using a typical Binding to my ViewModel.  It works beautifully, to source or to target, or so it seems.  The vm collection is an `ObservableCollection` which is initialized and never modified (no setter).

```
    public ObservableCollection<Statement> StatementsList { get; } = new();

    #region SelectedStatement
    private Statement _selectedStatement;
    public Statement SelectedStatement
    {
        get => _selectedStatement;
        set => Set(ref _selectedStatement, value, nameof(SelectedStatement));
    }
    #endregion SelectedStatement
```

I can set SelectedStatement from the ViewModel, and the UI updates fine.  I can watch the `SelectionChanged` event of the DataGrid and confirm the added items and removed items are exactly as expected.

Then, I select a different row USING THE MOUSE, and use my search function to select another row using `SelectedItem = some statement`, which visually selects the row perfectly (again), confirmed by the `SelectionChanged` event **again**.  `SelectedStatement` in my view model has the correct value!

Then, the weirdness starts.  I press the down arrow the **keyboard**.

You'd expect the next line after the selected statement to be selected, but instead the next line after the **previously selected** item (using the mouse) is selected.  It's like the keyboard responding code in the DataGrid is not recognizing the prior new row selection via the VM.

Has anyone seen this behavior?  I've done WPF development for many years, and I've seen many weird WPF bugs, but this one I've never noticed!

Note that `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on the DataGrid.  I tried setting it to false just as a stab in the dark, but no change in behavior.  I also tried changing my `SelectedItem` property to wrap a call to `GetDefaultCollectionView()` and getting/changing the selected item via the collection view instead of using a binding to `SelectedItem`.  The behavior is identical.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example of *how* you select the item. Are you sure that the setter of the `SelectedStatement` isn't set to another value than the one you expect?

Comment: I set it via SelectedStatement = some statement.  Like I say, it works perfectly and the DataGrid changes visually as expected, and the SelectionChanged even confirms the new statement was selected.  The new object is in the ItemsSource because otherwise none of this would work!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting an item is essentially setting IsSelected = true.
And setting this property does not affect the Focus transition to the selected element in any way.
And when controlling from the keyboard, the transition occurs from the element with Focus.

You can add the SelectionChanged processing to the Selector (ListBox, DataGrid,...) and in it perform the Focus transition to the selected item (by the index in the SelectedIndex).

An example of such a handler:

```
    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Selector selector)
        {
            int index = selector.SelectedIndex;
            if (index >=0)
            {
               var element = selector.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
                if (element is UIElement uiElement)
                    uiElement.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```